# How to install OpenSSH on Alpine?

Tags: linux, docker, installation, alpine-linux

When running an alpine docker container for the first time and attempting to install `openssh`, I get the following error:

```
ole@T:~$ docker run -it --rm alpine /bin/ash
/ # apk add openssh
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.d3812b7e.tar.gz: No such file or directory
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.bb2c5760.tar.gz: No such file or directory
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  openssh (missing):
    required by: world[openssh]
```

How can I install `openssh`?

Comment: Not answering, just sharing: [If you run SSHD in your Docker containers, you're doing it wrong!](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/) by [jpetazzo](https://github.com/jpetazzo/) -- docker dev.

Comment: Hello @Auzias - Excellent article - thank you.  I am installing the SSH server in order to be able to learn more about SSH and Alpine at the same time.  Basically a toy experiment.

Comment: @Auzias, ssh'ing to a container is useful for remote debugging python apps.

Comment: @Auzias From your link: `Unless your container is an SSH server, of course.` :)

Comment: @weberc2 obviously! @pitt I disagree, the best practice for this need is to run another docker with all your debugging tools and execute a `docker exec debugging-img --pid=container-to-debug`

Comment: Whats is important is in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` : `PermitRootLogin yes`

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Run `apk update` first.

A complete example:

```
    ole@T:~$ docker run -it --rm alpine /bin/ash
    / # apk update
    fetch http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.3/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
    fetch http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.3/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
    v3.3.1-97-g109077d [http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.3/main]
    v3.3.1-59-g48b0368 [http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.3/community]
    OK: 5853 distinct packages available
    / # apk add openssh
    (1/3) Installing openssh-client (7.1_p2-r0)
    (2/3) Installing openssh-sftp-server (7.1_p2-r0)
    (3/3) Installing openssh (7.1_p2-r0)
    Executing busybox-1.24.1-r7.trigger
    OK: 8 MiB in 14 packages
```

Comment: Or, to do and update and add in one shot: `RUN apk add --update openssh`

Comment: **RUN apk add --update --no-cache openssh**

Answer (score 91):

As the answer is already given but I will add up something.

In the new version, If you want to install something without caching things locally, which is recommended for keeping your containers small, include the `--no-cache` flag. Example:

```
apk add --no-cache openssh
```

This is a small gain, it keeps you from having the common `rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*` at the end of your Dockerfile.

Comment: thank you for --no-cache I was still using rm -rf hack

Answer (score 16):

Dockerfile for your reference

```
FROM alpine:3

RUN apk add --update --no-cache openssh

CMD ["ssh"]
```

Comment: `--update` is not an arg.