# Running OpenSSH in an Alpine Docker Container

Tags: linux, shell, docker, openssh, alpine-linux

I've [installed OpenSSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689976/installing-openssh-on-the-alpine-docker-container) and now I wish to run it as described in the [documentation](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_ssh-server) by running `/etc/init.d/sshd start`.  However it does not start:

```
 / # /etc/init.d/sshd start
 /bin/ash: /etc/init.d/sshd: not found
```

Thoughts?

P.S.

```
/ # ls -la /etc/init.d/sshd 
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          2622 Jan 14 20:48 /etc/init.d/sshd
```

Contents of /etc/init.d/sshd:

```
    #!/sbin/openrc-run
    # Copyright 1999-2015 Gentoo Foundation
    # Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License v2
    # $Header: /var/cvsroot/gentoo-x86/net-misc/openssh/files/sshd.rc6.4,v 1.5 2015/05/04 02:56:25 vapier Exp $

    description="OpenBSD Secure Shell server"
    description_checkconfig="Verify configuration file"
    description_reload="Reload configuration"

    extra_commands="checkconfig"
    extra_started_commands="reload"

    : ${SSHD_CONFDIR:=/etc/ssh}
    : ${SSHD_CONFIG:=${SSHD_CONFDIR}/sshd_config}
    : ${SSHD_PIDFILE:=/var/run/${SVCNAME}.pid}
    : ${SSHD_BINARY:=/usr/sbin/sshd}

    depend() {
        use logger dns
        if [ "${rc_need+set}" = "set" ] ; then
            : # Do nothing, the user has explicitly set rc_need
        else
            local x warn_addr
            for x in $(awk '/^ListenAddress/{ print $2 }' "$SSHD_CONFIG" 2>/dev/null) ; do
                case "${x}" in
                    0.0.0.0|0.0.0.0:*) ;;
                    ::|\[::\]*) ;;
                    *) warn_addr="${warn_addr} ${x}" ;;
                esac
            done
            if [ -n "${warn_addr}" ] ; then
                need net
                ewarn "You are binding an interface in ListenAddress statement in your sshd_config!"
                ewarn "You must add rc_need=\"net.FOO\" to your /etc/conf.d/sshd"
                ewarn "where FOO is the interface(s) providing the following address(es):"
                ewarn "${warn_addr}"
            fi
        fi
    }

    checkconfig() {
        if [ ! -d /var/empty ] ; then
            mkdir -p /var/empty || return 1
        fi

        if [ ! -e "${SSHD_CONFIG}" ] ; then
            eerror "You need an ${SSHD_CONFIG} file to run sshd"
            eerror "There is a sample file in /usr/share/doc/openssh"
            return 1
        fi

        if ! yesno "${SSHD_DISABLE_KEYGEN}"; then
            ssh-keygen -A || return 1
        fi

        [ "${SSHD_PIDFILE}" != "/var/run/sshd.pid" ] \
            && SSHD_OPTS="${SSHD_OPTS} -o PidFile=${SSHD_PIDFILE}"
        [ "${SSHD_CONFIG}" != "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" ] \
            && SSHD_OPTS="${SSHD_OPTS} -f ${SSHD_CONFIG}"

        "${SSHD_BINARY}" -t ${SSHD_OPTS} || return 1
    }

    start() {
        checkconfig || return 1

        ebegin "Starting ${SVCNAME}"
        start-stop-daemon --start --exec "${SSHD_BINARY}" \
            --pidfile "${SSHD_PIDFILE}" \
            -- ${SSHD_OPTS}
        eend $?
    }

    stop() {
        if [ "${RC_CMD}" = "restart" ] ; then
            checkconfig || return 1
        fi

        ebegin "Stopping ${SVCNAME}"
        start-stop-daemon --stop --exec "${SSHD_BINARY}" \
            --pidfile "${SSHD_PIDFILE}" --quiet
        eend $?

        if [ "$RC_RUNLEVEL" = "shutdown" ]; then
            _sshd_pids=$(pgrep "${SSHD_BINARY##*/}")
            if [ -n "$_sshd_pids" ]; then
                ebegin "Shutting down ssh connections"
                kill -TERM $_sshd_pids >/dev/null 2>&1
                eend 0
            fi
        fi
    }

    reload() {
        checkconfig || return 1
        ebegin "Reloading ${SVCNAME}"
        start-stop-daemon --signal HUP \
            --exec "${SSHD_BINARY}" --pidfile "${SSHD_PIDFILE}"
        eend $?
    }
```

Comment: Would you please try installing `openssh-server` by `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`?

Comment: It's an Alpine Linux container and it uses the apk package manager.  Please see the documentation link for more info.

Comment: Then `apk add openssh-server`. Adding `openssh-server` works in Debian systems. So just a thought.

Comment: What does `which sshd` return?

Comment: / # which sshd --- returns >>>
/usr/sbin/sshd

Comment: [Here is a post on why you SHOULD NOT use ssh in a container (written by a Docker Engineer)](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/)

Comment: Tha'ts an excellent post.  Sometimes it's just easier though, as with the gogs docker container: https://hub.docker.com/r/gogs/gogs/  Gogs needs SSH to support GIT.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A container is not a full installed environment.
The official document is for that installed alpine on some machine.
With power on, boot up services, etc. that a container does not have.

So, anything in `/etc/init.d/` can not be used directly in a container which is used by boot up service (like systemd, or alpine's rc*). That's why you got error messages cause the `rc*` isn't installed in the container.

What you need to do is start sshd manuanlly.
You can take look on below example:

https://hub.docker.com/r/danielguerra/alpine-sshd/~/dockerfile/

Comment: It's my understanding that example script ONLY can run sshd, and not any other command. How would you make it turn sshd + another application, whatever you specify as the command?

Comment: Link Only Answer :(

Comment: @CSJ I would think you would know better as a higher rep user but it's bad to avoid Link_Rot among other things --> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot

Answer (score 5):

> /etc/init.d/sshd: not found

Try to run these commands:

```
apk add --no-cache openrc
rc-update add sshd
```

Answer (score 4):

Despite there are some details still not clear to me, let me take a voice in the discussion. The solution specified by the below configuration works for me. It's the result of arduous experiments.

First, the **dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update && \
apk add --no-cache sudo bash openrc openssh
RUN mkdir -p /run/openrc && \
    touch /run/openrc/softlevel && \
    rc-update add sshd default
RUN adduser --disabled-password regusr && \
    sh -c 'echo "regusr:<encoded_passwd>"' | chpasswd -e > /dev/null 2>&1 && \
    sh -c 'echo "regusr ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL"' >> /etc/sudoers
VOLUME ["/home/reguser/solution/entrypoint-init.d","/sys/fs/cgroup"]
USER reguser
WORKDIR /home/reguser
RUN mkdir -p $HOME/solution && sudo chown reguser:reguser $HOME/solution
ADD ./entrypoint.sh /home/reguser/solution/
EXPOSE 22
ENTRYPOINT ["./solution/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Next, **/home/reguser/solution/entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in ./solution/entrypoint-init.d/*; do
    case "$f" in
       *.sh)     echo "$0: running $f"; . "$f" ;;
       *)        echo "$0: ignoring $f" ;;
    esac
    echo
done

exec "$@"
```

Next, **/home/reguser/solution/entrypoint-init.d/10-ssh-up.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^#[[:space:]]*Port[[:space:]]\+22$/ s/^#//i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^#[[:space:]]*AddressFamily[[:space:]]\+any$/ s/^#//i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^#[[:space:]]*HostKey[[:space:]]\+\/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_rsa_key$/ s/^#//i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config

sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^#[[:space:]]*HostbasedAuthentication[[:space:]].*/ s/^#//i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^[[:space:]]*HostbasedAuthentication[[:space:]].*/ s/^[[:space:]]*\(HostbasedAuthentication\)[[:space:]]\(.*\)/\1 no/i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^[[:space:]]*HostbasedAuthentication[[:space:]]\+yes.*/ s/^/#/i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config

sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^#[[:space:]]*IgnoreRhosts[[:space:]].*/ s/^#//i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^[[:space:]]*IgnoreRhosts[[:space:]].*/ s/^[[:space:]]*\(IgnoreRhosts\)[[:space:]]\(.*\)/\1 yes/i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^[[:space:]]*IgnoreRhosts[[:space:]]\+no.*/ s/^/#/i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config

sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^#[[:space:]]*PasswordAuthentication[[:space:]].*/ s/^#//i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^[[:space:]]*PasswordAuthentication[[:space:]].*/ s/^[[:space:]]*\(PasswordAuthentication\)[[:space:]]\(.*\)/\1 yes/i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^[[:space:]]*PasswordAuthentication[[:space:]]\+no.*/ s/^/#/i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config

sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^#[[:space:]]*PubkeyAuthentication[[:space:]].*/ s/^#//i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^[[:space:]]*PubkeyAuthentication[[:space:]].*/ s/^[[:space:]]*\(PubkeyAuthentication\)[[:space:]]\(.*\)/\1 yes/i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^[[:space:]]*PubkeyAuthentication[[:space:]]\+no.*/ s/^/#/i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config

sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^#[[:space:]]*PrintMotd[[:space:]].*/ s/^#//i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^[[:space:]]*PrintMotd[[:space:]].*/ s/^[[:space:]]*\(PrintMOTD\)[[:space:]]\(.*\)/\1 no/i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed --in-place --expression='/^[[:space:]]*PrintMotd[[:space:]]\+yes.*/ s/^/#/i' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config

sudo sed --in-place --expression='$ a\' --expression='\nAcceptEnv LANG LC_\*' -- /etc/ssh/sshd_config

sudo /etc/init.d/sshd --dry-run start
sudo /etc/init.d/sshd start
```

The last two lines are in the heart of the trick. In particular, the `sudo /etc/init.d/sshd --dry-run start` makes the solution working.

Finally, command-line controls

```
docker build --tag='dockerRegUser/sshdImg:0.0.1' --file='./dockerfile' .
docker container create --tty \
       --volume $(pwd)/dock/entrypoint-init.d:/home/reguser/solution/entrypoint-init.d:ro \
       --name sshdCnt 'dockerRegUser/sshdImg:0.0.1' tail -f /dev/null
docker start sshdCnt && \
ssh-keygen -f "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "$(docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' sshdCnt)" && \
sleep 5 && \
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/sshkey reguser@$(docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' sshdCnt)
```

I know, I know, there is a lot of unnecessary constructs. The example is also against the single service docker container principle. But there are phases and situations in solution development and delivery lifecycle that justify (or at least tempt) considering extending the container with the sshd or other openrc-controlled services.

Answer (score 0):

Check first is sshd is not present in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/sbin`.

Then, init.d should have sshd only if you set it up to  to automatically start wiht:

```
rc-update add sshd
rc-status
```

Comment: It is present is `usr/sbin`.  Also running `rc-update` results in `/bin/ash: rc-update: not found

`

Comment: when running that I get the same result >>> / # /usr/bin/sshd start
/bin/ash: /usr/bin/sshd: not found

Comment: I see the size of sshd is relatively small. Is it a script? Can you open it and see if it refers in it to non-existent paths?

Comment: I pasted the contents of `/etc/init.d/sshd in the question.  The contents of `/bin/sbin/sshd` are binary.

Comment: @Ole does `/sbin/openrc-run` exists?

Comment: No - BTW - @VonC you could just start a container and have a look like this: docker run -it --rm alpine /bin/ash

Answer (score 0):

I needed `sshd` for a very specific reason. I had to run front (`cypress`) and back (`django`) end tests on a CI server. Running them in one container is tricky at the least, so I decided to go with 2 containers. Also, there had to be one entrypoint that will run tests in both containers. So, the idea was that one container will run its tests, than run the tests in the other container over ssh.

In your case, you might not want to do exactly as I did, e.g. setting empty root password, empty passphrase.

It's best to run it in a separate directory, since it creates files (`id_rsa.pub`).

`server.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -eux
apk add openssh-server
ssh-keygen -A
passwd -d root
mkdir ~/.ssh
while ! [ -e id_rsa.pub ]; do sleep 1; done
cp id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
/usr/sbin/sshd -De
```

`client.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -eux
apk add openssh-client wait4ports
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -N ''
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub .
wait4ports -s 1 tcp://c1:22
ssh-keyscan -t rsa c1 > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh c1 echo DO SOMETHING
echo done
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    server:
        image: alpine:3.12
        command: sh -c 'cd app && ./server.sh'
        volumes:
            - .:/app
    client:
        image: alpine:3.12
        command: sh -c 'cd app && ./client.sh'
        volumes:
            - .:/app
```

```
$ docker-compose up -d && docker-compose logs -f
```

If you decide to run it again:

```
$ rm -f id_rsa.pub && docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d && docker-compose logs -f
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup openssh server on your docker container with alpine try this Dockerfile.

**In this example, I am using `docker:dind` image**

```
FROM docker:dind
# Setup SSH Service
RUN \
  apk update && \
  apk add openrc --no-cache && \
  apk add openssh-server && \
  rc-update add sshd && \
  rc-status && \
  touch /run/openrc/softlevel 

# Expose port for ssh
EXPOSE 22

# Start SSH Service
CMD ["sh" , "-c", "service sshd restart && sh"]
```

Once your container is up and running try running this command to make sure ssh works fine:

```sh
ssh localhost
```